# Why am I getting the error "Field: slug - 'slug' should match pattern "^[a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+$"."?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I got this error for the first time opening my project today. Im pretty sure nothing has changed since I last opened it, and didnt get the error. If you need versions or something lmk! Any help is appreciate more than you know! Thanks.

```
"expo": {
    "name": "MyApp",
    "slug": "MyApp",
    "version": "1.0.0",
```

Comment: Maybe you should share some code where you think the error is

Comment: The error is form my app.json file, and the code where the error lies is above.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the slug to "my-app".

Answer (score 0):

The slug has to match your project folder name

example:

my-project <-- your project folder name

so slug has to be

"slug": "my-project",